# I have a program where i would like to validate user input in java i want the user to input a double value and only a double value any suggestions?

Tags: java, user-input

I did what i could and now the code works however when the user inputs the wrong value and is prompted to try again you have to hit enter and then you are asked to input a value, i cant think of what it is.
i also want to be able to get the program to start again after completing, i tried a do, while loop but it looped infinitely

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   String nameOfIngredient = null;
   Float numberOfCups = null;
   Float numberOfCaloriesPerCup = null;
   Float totalCalories;
   
  
   while(nameOfIngredient == null)
   {nameOfIngredient = setIngredients(); }// Allows us to loop

   while(numberOfCups == null)
    {numberOfCups = setNumberOfCups(); }// Allows us too loop
    
   while(numberOfCaloriesPerCup == null)
    {numberOfCaloriesPerCup = setNumberOfCalories();} // Allows us to loop

   totalCalories = numberOfCups * numberOfCaloriesPerCup;
    
    System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberOfCups + " cups and this amount contains " + totalCalories + " total calories.");
    System.out.print("\n");
   

}

//A method to be called on in the main class while loop making it easier to read and maintain 
public static String setIngredients() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        String ingredients = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\r");
        return ingredients;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Error taking in input, try again");
    }

    return null;
}
//A method to be called on in the main class while loop making it easier to read and maintain
public static Float setNumberOfCups() {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Number Of Cups: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        String numberOfCups = scan.nextLine();
        Float numberOfCupsFloat = Float.parseFloat(numberOfCups);
        System.out.println("\n");
        return numberOfCupsFloat;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException){
        System.out.println("Invalid Input must be a numeric value Please Try Again: ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Error taking in input, try again.");
    }
    return null;
}
//A method to be called on in the main class while loop making it easier to read and maintain
public static Float setNumberOfCalories() {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Number Of Calories per cup: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        String numberOfCalories = scan.nextLine();
        Float numberOfCaloriesFloat = Float.parseFloat(numberOfCalories);
         System.out.println("\n");
        return numberOfCaloriesFloat;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException){
        System.out.println("Invalid value Please enter a numeric value:");// if the input is incorrect the user gets prompted for the proper input
        scan.nextLine();// if the input is incorrect the user gets prompted for the proper input 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Error in input please try again.");
    }   

    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to support fractional numbers?  A value like "2/3 cup" is super common in recipes, but takes special handling in your code to support.

Comment: read in as a string, then validate

Comment: @Gus i did not think bout that but i will most likely need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to accept it as a string and check if it is numeric or not using String methods. Post that you can either move forward if format is correct or re prompt the user for correct value while showing the error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String nameOfIngredient = "";
        double numberCups = 0.0;
        int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
        double totalCalories = 0.0;
        
        System.out.println("Please Enter Ingredient Name: ");
        nameOfIngredient = scnr.nextLine(); //In case ingredient is more than one word long. 
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of " + nameOfIngredient + " required: ");
        String numCups = scnr.next();
        while(!numCups.chars().allMatch( Character::isDigit ))
        {
             System.out.println("Incorrect format for number of cups. Please enter numeric values");
             numCups = scnr.next();
        }
        numberCups = Double.parseDouble(numCups);
            
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per cup of " + nameOfIngredient + " : ");
        numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();
        
        totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;
        
        System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberCups + " cups and this amount contains " + totalCalories + " total calories.");
        
    }
```

Alternatively you could also do this using try catch statements. I believe this would be a better way to parse double values

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String nameOfIngredient = "";
        double numberCups = 0.0;
        int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
        double totalCalories = 0.0;
        
        System.out.println("Please Enter Ingredient Name: ");
        nameOfIngredient = scnr.nextLine(); //In case ingredient is more than one word long. 
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of " + nameOfIngredient + " required: ");
        String numCups = scnr.next();
        while(numberCups==0.0)
        {
            try {
                numberCups = Double.parseDouble(numCups);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect format for number of cups. Please enter numeric values");
                numCups = scnr.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per cup of " + nameOfIngredient + " : ");
        numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();
        
        totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;
        
        System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberCups + " cups and this amount contains " + totalCalories + " total calories.");
        
    }
```

Comment: I see, however i get the InputMismatchException error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at SteppingStone2_IngredientCalculator.main(SteppingStone2_IngredientCalculator.java:47)  how do i bypass this?

Comment: Which line is line 47 in your code?
Did you try the first code or second?

Comment: i used the second code, i don't  have a 47th line i have a total of 40

Comment: Are you using scnr.nextDouble in your code? Can you use the debugger in ide to identify which line the error is coming from?

Comment: i am, i now have it working to where it will print the error message if it is the incorrect input but now it will only print the error message regardless of the input so i am getting there just a little stuck  while(numberOfCups == 0.0){String numCups = scnr.nextLine();
  try{
                numberOfCups = Double.parseDouble(numCups);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Error- the value you have entered for number of cups is non numeric, please enter a numeric value: ");
                numCups = scnr.nextLine(); 
            }

Comment: Please paste your entire code. You could alternatively try printing out the exception and see where you are going wrong. I suspect you are using scnr.next() before the while loop as well

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and added support for input of fractional numbers.  Comments added on important changes.

- `parseCups` returns an `Optional` so we can tell if the input was valid or not.
- `parseIngredientValue` does the work of deciding whether or not the input is a fraction and/or attempting to parse the input as a Double.

```
package SteppingStone;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SteppingStone2_IngredientCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nameOfIngredient = "";
        String cupsStr = "";
        double numberCups = 0.0;
        int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
        double totalCalories = 0.0;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Ingredient Name: ");
        nameOfIngredient = scnr.nextLine(); // In case ingredient is more than one word long.

        Optional<Double> cups = Optional.empty();
        while (cups.isEmpty()) { // repeat until we've got a value
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of " + nameOfIngredient + " required: ");
            cupsStr = scnr.nextLine();
            cups = parseCups(cupsStr);
        }
        numberCups = cups.get();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per cup of " + nameOfIngredient + " : ");
        numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();

        totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;
        // Using String.format to allow rounding to 2 decimal places (%2.2f)
        System.out.println(String.format("%s uses %2.2f cups and this amount contains %2.2f total calories.",
                nameOfIngredient, numberCups, totalCalories));
    }

    private static double parseIngredientValue(String input) {
        if (input.contains("/")) { // it's a fraction, so do the division
            String[] parts = input.trim().split("/");
            double numerator = (double) Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            double denomenator = (double) Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            return numerator / denomenator;
        } else { // it's not a fraction, just try to parse it as a double
            return Double.parseDouble(input);
        }
    }

    private static Optional<Double> parseCups(String cupsStr) {
        double result = 0.0;
        String input = cupsStr.trim();
        String[] parts = input.split(" +"); // split on any space, so we can support "1 2/3" as an input value
        switch (parts.length) {
        case 2:
            result += parseIngredientValue(parts[1]); // add the 2nd part if it's there note that there's no
                                                        // break here, it will always continue into the next case
        case 1:
            result += parseIngredientValue(parts[0]); // add the 1st part
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unable to parse " + cupsStr);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(result);
    }

}
```

Sample run:

```
Please Enter Ingredient Name: 
Special Sauce
Please enter the number of cups of Special Sauce required: 
2 2/3
Please enter the number of calories per cup of Special Sauce : 
1500
Special Sauce uses 2.67 cups and this amount contains 4000.00 total calories.
```

Comment: This is awesome it works perfect but i dont know how to incorporate it into my code i re-wrote it so it is not the same.

Comment: @ThatGuy The loop I added (starting with the Optional declaration, through `numberCups=cups.get()` is sort of equivalent to your ` while(numberOfCups == null)
    {numberOfCups = setNumberOfCups(); } ` . You don't need to use the Optional, since your other methods seem to be just returning a null value directly, and that's also fine.  So, you could move the code I added (minus the additional while loop) into your `setNumberOfCups`, and then re-use the method declarations for `parseIngredientValue` and `parseCups` or whatever your equivalents are

Comment: It worked! thank you @Gus